# How i can read a table from COM when i have a .NET TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, com, vb6

I have a situation like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void net_call_com_in_transaction()
{
    TransactionOptions tranOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    tranOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOptions))
    {
        // ...someCode that Update Table1 with SqlCommand instructions
        COMWrapper wrapper = GetComWrapper();
        wrapper.Publish();
        // otherCode....
        scope.Commit();
    }
}
```

I open a transaction with TransactionScopeOption 'Required' and, inside it, i update **Table1** through SqlCommand.
Subsequently, as you can see in the code above, i call a COM Object in Interop (*wrapper.Publish()* - always within the transaction) that it read one **Table1** (inside method Publish()).
The problem is that the reading of **Table1** from COM is **pending** because i have the .NET transaction that lock the **Table1**. At this point you will say: *"You should read Table1 in COM with instruction WITH (NOLOCK)"* but i can't do that for otherwise reasons.

So, there is an other a solution that permit me to read **Table1** in COM without pending state?

Comment: Be careful using ReadUncommitted. It is far more sinister than most people think. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: i know...thanks you for suggestion